# "Failed to enumerate SSL bindings" error code 234

Tags: iis, powershell, ssl, binding

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Replicate when you type the following command in PowerShell.

```
dir iis:\sslbindings
```

I have comes across [this page on Microsoft TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/87b1252d-a6a0-4251-bbb6-38e104a8c07a/enumerating-iissslbindings-gives-failure-on-one-machine-works-on-another?forum=winserverpowershell) which doesn't address the problem.

#### Edit

When invoking the command I get the error

> failed to enumerate SSL bindings

Apparently due to a corrupted registry?

Comment: That command requires "import-module WebAdministration" within PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the delay but I resolved the issue with the following script (see below). For some bizarre reason (I don't know why) something was adding two entries in my registry and after removing these the problem went away. I figured this out as I compared my registry to another machine who wasn't having this problem and found the culprit.

```
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo\" -Name "[::1]:26143" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo" -Name "127.0.0.1:26143" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

echo "Done."
```

@Bewc I reckon you are onto something there although I think it affects more than just WCF services. We have a powershell script that builds and deploys a website onto a machine (sounds crazy I know). Who or what creates these entries I have no idea but perhaps some background process in IIS?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I've got the error when I had both SslCertStoreName and DefaultSslCtlStoreName in the registry. I deleted DefaultSslCtlStoreName and the error is gone for a while. For some reason, DefaultSslCtlStoreName was created in the registry again, and I've got the error again. So I wrote a simple powershell script that deletes it.

This is the part from my build script.

```
function CleanupSslBindings() 
{
    $sslBindingsPath = 'hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo\'
    $registryItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $sslBindingsPath |
        Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.Property -eq 'DefaultSslCtlStoreName')}

    If ($registryItems.Count -gt 0) {
        ForEach ($item in $registryItems) {
            $item | Remove-ItemProperty -Name DefaultSslCtlStoreName
            Write-Host "Deleted DefaultSslCtlStoreName in " $item.Name
        }
    } Else {
        Write-Host "No DefaultSslCtlStoreName found. The SSL Bindings registry is clean."
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I was getting weird issues as stated above on my machine when i was trying to auto setup IIS using powershell and this solved it. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had built WCF services hosted as windows services.  When I did this, I apparently didn't know (and still don't) how to assign things like appid's (noticeable when you netsh http show sslcert), and other items that crop up...  including an item related to this error.

Essentially, I read the same page the OP did: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/87b1252d-a6a0-4251-bbb6-38e104a8c07a/enumerating-iissslbindings-gives-failure-on-one-machine-works-on-another?forum=winserverpowershell

...and using a regedit, went to the key: HKLM\System\Currentcontrolset\services\http\parameters\sslbindinginfo

I saw all the same entries I see when I do the netsh command above.  However, my wcf services are listed first, followed by my IIS sites.  None of my wcf services had the SSLCertStoreName key (only the IIS sites had the key).  Following the article's explanation that the first entry needs to have that registry key (this is a bug in my opinion), I performed the following PowerShell commands:

```
Try
{
    Get-ChildItem IIS:\SslBindings
}
Catch
{
    $1stentry = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo | Select-Object -First 1
    $1stentry | New-ItemProperty -Name "SslCertStoreName" -Value "MY"
    Get-ChildItem IIS:\SslBindings
}
```

**This code works for me.**  And that article helped get me here and understand that my root cause of this 234 error code, is an assumed self-inflicted wound by not installing my WCF services correctly.  YMMV.  Hope this helps.